# Triggering stored procedure from script task in SSIS - login failed error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a 2008 SSIS package that have a lot of steps, one of the steps is a script task that runs a stored procedure. It is not an option for now to change it from a script task, as it would require a lot of extra developing. The procedure runs fine in the production environment, but I need to be able to test it from VS.

The reason for the failure I have found is that the connection to the target database is not working, it is giving error "Login failed for user 'user'".

The SSIS package is built on a SSIS framework, and it has a "Initialize Connections" task as an Event in the "Initialize" part of the package. I do not know much about what this does. I want to just run the Data Flow (With "Execute task" option inside the Data Flow).

In the ProtectionLevel for the package I have tried both DontSaveSensitive and EncryptSensitiveWithPassword without any luck. I manually insert the password in the Connection Manager.

I read some about the need to use a connection manager/XML file, but I'm unsure of how this can be done. (Not done much SSIS before).

Please explain how this debugging in VS should be done.

Comment: What does the (anonymized) connection string look like?

Comment: Added some X and 0 for anonymization: Data Source=X-1XX-2X0-000\MS_XX_TEST;User ID=ETL_Admin;Initial Catalog=VL_XX_DWH;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;Packet Size=32767;Application Name=SSIS-XX_Dimension-{A6C000X8-X0X4-0090-AAE6-X60XX300020}Production; - I got the connection sting from: IDTSConnectionManager100 connectionManager = this.Connections.Target; inside the script.

Comment: I did copy the script step into a new package, and made two new test tables in the same database to read/write from and to, and it worked when running it from this package, the connection sting I got from that package (no changes done in the package to modify security etc) was this: Data Source=X-100-000-000\MS_XX_TEST;Initial Catalog=VL_XX_DWH;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-TestPkg-{11XX0000-XX00-XX25-B3XX-XX0000006DB5}X-000-000-000\MS_XX_TEST.VL_XX_DWH;Auto Translate=False;